# Datos repetidos al recorrer un array y mostrarlos en una lista

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente código: (también disponible en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jv_13/pen/PjWgLN?editors=0010))

```css
const agregar=document.querySelector('#agregar')
const inputAgregar=document.querySelector('#inputAgregar') 
const listaUl=document.querySelector('#listaUl') 

var datosArray=[] 

agregar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (inputAgregar.value=='') {
    alert('Esta vacio') 
    inputAgregar.focus()
  } else {
    datosArray.push(inputAgregar.value) 
    inputAgregar.value='' 
    inputAgregar.focus() 
    mostrar(datosArray)
  }
}) 

function mostrar(datosArray) {
  for( i of datosArray) {
    var listaLi=document.createElement('li')
    listaUl.appendChild(listaLi) 
    listaLi.innerText=datosArray 
    console.log(datosArray)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputAgregar">
<p>
  <button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
</p>
<ul id="listaUl"></ul>
```

¿Por qué me salen los datos repetidos al recorrer un array y mostrarlos en una lista en JavaScript?

Comment: Que es lo que quieres lograr? Crear un ´li´ por cada elemento del array al clickear en "agregar"? O mostrar en un único ´li´ el contenido completo de tu array?

Comment: Que se inserte en el array y despues me lo itere con un for mostrardolo en la lista ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios detalles:

- El primero es que para evitar errores y por buenas prácticas debe ir `;` al final de cada sentencia.
- El segundo detalle es que tus variables tienen el mismo nombre de id, muchos navegadores usan el id como una variable global por lo que al final puede salir error al querer crear una constante con ese mismo nombre.
- Por último tu error está, en que estás recorriendo el array y agregando todo el array a cada `li`  en vez de cada elemento del array y tampoco estás limpiando el elemento `ul` para volver a agregar todos de nuevo cada vez que se llama al método `mostrar`.

```js
const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#agregar');
const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputAgregar');
const listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#listaUl');

var datosArray = [];


agregarVar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (inputAgregarVar.value == '') {
    alert('Esta vacio');
    inputAgregar.focus();
  } else {
    datosArray.push(inputAgregarVar.value)
    inputAgregarVar.value = '';
    inputAgregarVar.focus();

    mostrar(datosArray);


  }
});

function mostrar(datosArray) {
  listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
  for (elemento of datosArray) {
    var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
    listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);
    listaLi.innerText = elemento;
    console.log(elemento);

  }




}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputAgregar">
<p>
  <button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
</p>
<ul id="listaUl"></ul>
```

Comment: pero mas importante ya que es por lo que le duplica resultados, que lo realizaste pero no lo explicaste, tiene que vaciar su lista al iniciar mostrar `listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: Gracias, creia que en js 6 no se necesitaba el ;

Comment: Cierto @JorgeArturoJuarez, se me fue, ahora lo agrego.